# replacing the_autor or make callback

Tags: post-meta, loop

I'm looking a way tho change the `the_author();` function in the loop,
I have post meta data with the name of the user who posted.

I need to do this:

- If the user is registered, show `the_author();`, but if isn't show the data from the post meta.

Since `the_author()`, function doesn't have a callback function I'm a little lost, maybe making a function?

The idea is replace `the_author()` in my theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to change the `the_author()` function itself. A simple conditional tag will do the trick. Example:

```
<?php

/*** on your functions.php file ***/
function ifRegistered() {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        the_author();
    } else {
        echo get_the_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_post_meta_key', true);
        // or anything else, of course
    }
}

/*** on the template you want to use the function  **/

// your HTML markup ...

    ifRegistered();

// more possible HTML ...

?>
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Updated the function.

Comment: Looking for registered user not current logged in user, but i have the idea, is possible to make it like a function to replace the the_author(), for my custom function on every template file? Thanks.

Comment: If the user is logged in, it means he/she is registered. Edited my answer with the function.